# Access a C++ struct in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a [VC++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) stucture like

```
struct VideoInputV20 {
   int m_nBrightness;
   int m_nSharpness;
   int m_nSaturation;
   int m_nContrast;
   int m_nInputState;
   CString m_sObjref;
};
```

Here in C# I'll receive this stucture in byte[]. Here I need to convert byte[] to stuct.

How can I achive this? Please provide sample code, if possible.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking... can you rephrase this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]  
struct VideoInputV20
{
    int m_nBrightness;
    int m_nSharpness;
    int m_nSaturation;
    int m_nContrast;
    int m_nInputState;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string m_sObjref;
}
```

Then the code to get it out of a byte[]

```
GCHandle handle = new GCHandle();
try
{
    // Pin the byte[]
    handle = GCHandle.Alloc(yourByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // Marshal byte[] into struct instance
    VideoInputV20 myVideoInputV20 = (VideoInputV20 )Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(VideoInputV20 ));
}
// Clean up memory
finally
{
    if (handle.IsAllocated) handle.Free();
}
```

Comment: what is GCHandle how i declare in .net2003

Comment: You need to add the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace, it should then be available. It is part of the .NET framework 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Badly. Ints are relatively easy to recover, but that CString's object serialization is platform and compiler dependent. Try converting this in C++ to some other representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] data = GetData();
int structSize = Marshal.SizeOf(VideoInputV20);

if(structSize <= data.Length)
{
   IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structSize);
   Marshal.Copy(data, 0, buffer, structSize);
   VideoInputV20 vi = (VideoInputV20)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, VideoInputV20);
   Marshal.FreeHGlobal( buffer );
}
```